# Regular expression to filter a word that's somewhere in the middle of a string

Tags: regex, jenkins-groovy

I've following (short url) strings which can be in these 3 ways:

1. abc-xy-helloWorld
2. abc-xy-helloWorld-welcome
3. abc-xy-helloWorld-welcome-home

I need to filter 'helloWorld' string only and following `(?<=abc-xy-).*` works for case #1 but how can I make it work for all 3 cases such that it filters only 'helloWorld' regardless of input is 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: What does `nsregularexpression` have to do with Groovy?

Comment: Did the solution below help, or shall we close the question?

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` part matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

In your strings, the `helloWord` is followed with a `-` char, and the `helloWorld` only consists of letters.

So, possible solutions here are

```
(?<=abc-xy-)[a-zA-Z]+
(?<=abc-xy-)\w+
(?<=abc-xy-)[^-]+
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iEwxHZ/2).

The `[a-zA-Z]+` variant will match one or more ASCII letters, `\w+` will match one or more letters, digits or underscores, and `[^-]+` will match one or more chars other than `-`.

Note I use `[^-\n]` in the regex testing site because the input is a single multiline text, while in real life situation, you have these strings as separate inputs.

Comment: It works mighty fine.